# Call extension methods for Nullable<T> with ?. in chain

Tags: c#, extension-methods, nullable

Why does C# not allow to concat methods with `?.` in chain?

```cs
class X {
  public static Timestamp ToTimestamp(this System.DateTime dateTime);

  public void Demo()
  {
    System.DateTime? dateTime = GetFromSomewhere();
    Timestamp? good = (dateTime?.ToUniversalTime())?.ToTimestamp();
    Timestamp? bad = dateTime?.ToUniversalTime()?.ToTimestamp();
  }
}
```

I was very surprised that the line with bad gives a compilation error:

```
error CS0023: Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'DateTime'
```

How adding of braces can change the type here?

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```cs
Timestamp? good = (dateTime?.ToUniversalTime())?.ToTimestamp();
```

is equivalent to this:

```cs
DateTime? temp = dateTime?.ToUniversalTime();
Timestamp? good = temp?.ToTimestamp();
```

The original code evaluates the expression in the parentheses first, which can be a `DateTime` or can be `null`. That means that using a null-forgiving operator is allowed. This code:

```cs
Timestamp? bad = dateTime?.ToUniversalTime()?.ToTimestamp();
```

is not the same. In order for `ToUniversalTime` to be called, `dateTime` must not be `null`, so the result of calling `ToUniversalTime` cannot be null, so you can't apply a null-forging operator to that result. That code is equivalent to this:

```cs
Timestamp? bad = dateTime == null
                     ? null
                     : dateTime.Value.ToUniversalTime()?.ToTimestamp();
```

The result of `dateTime.Value.ToUniversalTime()` is not nullable so the null-forgiving operator is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong:

```cs
Timestamp? bad = dateTime?.ToUniversalTime()?.ToTimestamp();
```

`ToUniversalTime()` returns `DateTime`, non-nullable.
You can simply use: `dateTime?.ToUniversalTime().ToTimestamp()`

if datetime is null, null will be returned, else `ToUniversalTime().ToTimestamp()` will be called.

That is why `(dateTime?.ToUniversalTime())?.ToTimestamp()` does work, if `dateTime?.ToUniversalTime()` is null, the value will be null, else  `.ToTimestamp()` will be called.

Notice the difference here;

`dateTime?.ToUniversalTime().ToTimestamp()`
Will  return null, or whatever `ToTimeStamp()` returns.

`(dateTime?.ToUniversalTime())?.ToTimestamp()`
will always return whatever `ToTimeStamp()` returns